# Code in C: issue on int array function argument in 64-bit systems

Tags: c, arrays, linux, pointers, 64-bit

The following C code works perfectly on a 32-bit Linux, but not in 64-bit systems:

```
#define MAX 5

int change(int** ns) {
  ns[0] = 111;
  ns[1] = 222;
  ns[2] = 333;
}

int main() {
  int i, nums[MAX];
  memset(nums, 0, sizeof(nums));
  change((int**) &nums);
  for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    printf("nums[%d] = %d\n", i, nums[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Linux 32-bit (x86):

```
$ uname -a
Linux host-1549776 3.2.0-58-generic-pae #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 18:00:02 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

$ gcc inta.c -o inta
$ ./inta
nums[0] = 111
nums[1] = 222
nums[2] = 333
nums[3] = 0
nums[4] = 0
```

Linux 64-bit (x86_64):

```
$ uname -a
Linux host-1530141 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 11 22:03:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gcc inta.c -o inta
$ ./inta
nums[0] = 111
nums[1] = 0
nums[2] = 222
nums[3] = 0
nums[4] = 333
```

I've read that integer pointers in C are 4 bytes long in 32-bit and 8 bytes in 64-bit, but I couldn't figure out how to solve this issue in order to make it a portable code no matter the architecture.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is this thing supposed to do?  Why are you treating the members of 'nums' as pointers when they are not?

Answer (score 5):

A good debugger will help you to find compile-time errors and warnings for simple issues, such as those you have in your code.  For example:

When I attempt to compile this with all warnings turned on (CLANG), the problems are clearly shown in warnings:

```
play_6.c - 5 warnings 
    5,9 warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int'[-Wpointer-int-conv]
    6,9 warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int'[-Wpointer-int-conv]
    7,9 warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int'[-Wpointer-int-conv]
    8,1 warning: function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
    10,5 warning: function declaration isnt a prototype. [-Wstrict-prototypes]
```

You are attempting an illegal pointer conversion

```
int change(int** ns) {
  ns[0] = 111; //here
  ns[1] = 222; //here
  ns[2] = 333; //here
  return 0; //add return statement here
}
```

***To address these issues***:
Change this line in main:

```
change((int**) &nums);//nums is already a pointer, no need to dereference
                      //and casting to int ** is also a problem
```

to

```
change( nums);
```

And change your prototype from:

```
int change(int** ns) {
```

to:

```
int change(int* ns) {
```

***Next***, add a return statement to the `change` function.
**Note**: In your function definition:

```
int change(int* ns);
```

The first `int` says you want the function to return an `int` value.  If you want to use the function without requiring a return, create it as:

```
void change(int *ns);
```

***And finally***, when I run your code, with the changes above, in either 32bit or 64 bit targets, the results are the same:

```
nums[0] = 111
nums[1] = 222
nums[2] = 333
nums[3] = 0
nums[4] = 0
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the `clang` warnings as text?  My corporate overlords don't allow me to visit `imgur`.

Comment: @PeterM - I am not sure I follow what you are asking.  What is `imgur`?  Essentially, the text is: Warning: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion: assigning to int ** from int [W-pointer-int-conv].  This same text is repeated three times, once for each occurrence. as well as similar warning for not having a prototype, and not using a return statement. (both related)

Comment: Stackoverflow hosts images on `i.stack.imgur.com`, which is where your `clang` image is hosted by the site.  While my corporate overlords allow access to `stackoverflow.com`, I can't see anything on the `imgur.com` domain.  So for your image all I see is a broken link.  This is really my problem, not yours, but I am sure other people are in the same boat, plus google can't index the warning.

Comment: @PeterM -  My compiler will not let me cut and paste that content unfortunately.  Does the text in comment help?

Comment: yes it helps, but to be really annoying I'd suggest putting it in your answer!

Comment: Note: on-line sites like https://www.newocr.com almost does it: "E}  play_6.c - 5 warnings ...g -6, 9 waming: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to int “from ’Int' [.Wpointerintconv] ..."

Comment: @PeterM - added a text version of the comment to post.  However,  pictures are a part of the accepted post content on Stackoverflow, Overloards not withstanding.  Until now, I have never been requested to convert to text.  Tell your Overlords to lighten up a little :)

Comment: @Chux - Can you see the picture okay?  Are you aware of an emerging difficulty among others recently in accessing image content?

Comment: Picture is clear and fine. I have no problem with the picture - just thought I would comment of an aid to help OCR it.   A difficulty in using picture content instead of text includes searching post/answers on keywords - which of course a picture does not match.  Unclear why an unedited OCR of the picture was posted.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick and precise help. The final code is working on both platforms now: [link](https://github.com/hjort/mega-sena/blob/master/lab/sortear.c)

Comment: @chux - Thanks.  I removed the redundant picture and edited the OCR text version.

Comment: @chux - have always found your comments positive and useful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your working code:

```
#define MAX 5

int change(int ns[])
{
  ns[0] = 111;
  ns[1] = 222;
  ns[2] = 333;
}

int main()
{
    int i, nums[MAX];
    memset(nums, 0, sizeof(nums));
    change(nums);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        printf("nums[%d] = %d\n", i, nums[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

You don't need to pass `(int**) &nums` to `change` as array is already pass by reference.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick answer! I didn't realize that arrays were already passed by reference. It worked as expected in both platforms.